# gzipping files from python is changing the file names

Tags: python

I am trying to gzip files using python 3. When I gzip the files, the code is changing the filename without me doing anything. I am not sure I totally understand the working of gzip module.

Below is the code:

```
dir_in = '/localfolder/new_files/'
dir_out = '/localfolder/zippedfiles/
file_name = 'transactions_may05'
def gzip_files(dir_in, dir_out, file_name):
    with open(dir_in + file_name, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(dir_out + 'unprocessed.' + file_name + '.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(f_in)
```

**Expected Output:**
**Outer file:** `unprocessed.transactions_may05.gz`
when I double click it, I should get the original file `transactions_may05`

**Current Output:
Outer file:** `unprocessed.transactions_may05.gz` -- As expected
when I double click it the internal file also has unprocessed. appended to it. I am not sure why unprocessed. gets appended to internal file name
**Internal File:**`unprocessed.transactions_may05`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Python is working correctly. As Gzip is not an archive format, all gunzip (or other implementations) can do is to strip the .gz extension when it inflates. If you wish to dictate the output filename, use an archive format like tar or zip.

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behavior of gzip and gunzip.
As mentioned in the manual page:

> gunzip  takes  a  list of files on its command line and replaces each
>   file whose name ends with .gz, -gz, .z, -z, or _z (ignoring case) and
>   which begins with  the  correct magic  number  with an uncompressed
>   file without the original extension.

If you don't want the name to change, you should not modify the filename when you compress it.